# how to create npm package with a demo app?

Tags: javascript, npm, package-development

It seems good practice for packages to provide some type of demo app, so I'm just wondering what's the cleanest way to organize the file structure?

I want to have one github repo that contains my published NPM module and a simple demo webapp.

Ideally I would like a top level like:

```
package/
demo/
```

and have the code just in `package/` get distributed to NPM. 
I could use the `package.json` files option like

```
files: [ 'package' ]
```

But then all the code will get distributed with that path prefix, eg

```
node_modules/MyPackageName/package/index.js
```

Is there a way to modify the path prefix so it changes the top-level directory and removes the extra `package/` I used to organize the files?

Sure other people have ways to do this, but I'd prefer not to use two repos - one demo and one package.

**Clarification** I want to be able to install the package directly from github, as a kind of "poor-mans private NPM". So I don't want to just publish from within the 'package' directory. I think using github URLs you can specify a branch to use, but not a subdirectory.

Comment: So you want to use one repository and publish a subdirectory to npm? Just put the `package.json` inside `package/` and make that the top-level directory of your npm module.

Comment: good point, added clarification that I want to use from github URLs to install also, so not just remote publishing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of NODE_PATH env variable:

`export NODE_PATH='yourdir'/node_modules`

[Reference](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders)

> If the NODE_PATH environment variable is set to a colon-delimited list of absolute paths, then Node.js will search those paths for modules if they are not found elsewhere.
>
> On Windows, NODE_PATH is delimited by semicolons (;) instead of colons.
>
> NODE_PATH was originally created to support loading modules from varying paths before the current module resolution algorithm was frozen.
>
> NODE_PATH is still supported, but is less necessary now that the Node.js ecosystem has settled on a convention for locating dependent modules. Sometimes deployments that rely on NODE_PATH show surprising behavior when people are unaware that NODE_PATH must be set. Sometimes a module's dependencies change, causing a different version (or even a different module) to be loaded as the NODE_PATH is searched.
>
> Additionally, Node.js will search in the following list of GLOBAL_FOLDERS:
>
> 1: $HOME/.node_modules
>   2: $HOME/.node_libraries
>   3: $PREFIX/lib/node
>   Where $HOME is the user's home directory, and $PREFIX is Node.js's configured node_prefix.
>
> These are mostly for historic reasons.
>
> It is strongly encouraged to place dependencies in the local node_modules folder. These will be loaded faster, and more reliably.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. this may make the require look cleaner in the code, but the files are still spread out and now we have a dependency on special magic environment configuration for a level of redirection.

Comment: @dcsan unfortunately that's kind of what you're asking for with a request like this